# At what level of a React application can I handle an error from an improperly decoded URI component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, react-router-dom, browser-history

I have this as the pathname `/products/brushes-eye%0&%20brow%20brushes`. The %0&%20 causes the `URIError: Failed to decode param '/products/brushes-eye%0&%20brow%20brushes'` error. I wish to be able to intercept this error and maybe go back with the history object or render a different page. How would you suggest I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use starkstring module, that has fixURL function to do that
https://www.npmjs.com/package/starkstring

```js
starkString(
  "https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D9%87%D9%94_%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%84%DB%8C",
)
  .fixURL()
  .toString(); //returns https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/صفحهٔ_اصلی
```